# Unable to find reference for VIBBTSCompLib which uses definition BTSComp and BTSCompClass

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, biztalk, resolveassemblyreference

We're migrating few of the files from older frame work to VS2103 FW-4.5.1.
On migrating one of the Solution files there is a reference to Interop.VIBBTSCompLib.dll, but I'm unable to find such a dll or any other higher level DLL. Also on little more search seems like this is related to BizTalk Server, but I'm unable to find any of the references in Visual studio 2013,

The definitions and functions using this reference are "BTSComp", "BTSCompClass()" and "ProcessMessage(XMLText)".

Comment: Are you migrating from BizTalk Server 2000 or 2002?

Comment: No, it is from VS 2008 to VS 2013

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 SP1?  Then it would have been BizTalk 2009 if it is a BizTalk project.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amantaras/2010/04/21/visual-studio-versions-needed-by-each-release-of-biztalk/